# What is the board game Rollo and the King are playing?

Tags: vikings

What is that game the Rollo and King Horik are playing in Season 1, Episode 9?

Is it a real game or just something for our eyes?

Comment: Related: [How is Hnefatafl related to Chess and Go?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/how-is-hnefatafl-related-to-chess-and-go)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Vikings had a board games called Hnefatafl, which was played on a 9 by 9 board. The game is played with 2 uneven sides unlike chess where both players start with identical numbers of pieces.
 It is mentioned in sagas and there are carvings of what are probably people playing the game. However there are no records of how the game was actually played, there are some clues and guesses but no one knows for sure.